# Rows within a norm

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation

Is there a way to take a matrix and select the rows (or columns) with norm lesser than a certain amount max. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[1]
mat = RandomInteger[100, {5, 5}];

TeXForm @ MatrixForm @ mat
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  80 & 14 & 0 & 67 & 3 \\
>  65 & 100 & 23 & 97 & 68 \\
>  74 & 15 & 24 & 4 & 100 \\
>  90 & 83 & 70 & 1 & 30 \\
>  48 & 25 & 44 & 73 & 69 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
N[Norm /@ mat]
```

> ```
>  {105.328, 169.667, 127.644, 144.187, 122.291}
> ```

```
max = 130;
```

You can use [`Select`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html), [`Pick`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html), [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html)  or [`DeleteCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) as follows:

```
Select[Norm[#] <= max &] @ mat
Pick[mat, Norm[#] <= max & /@ mat ]
Pick[mat, UnitStep[ max - Norm /@ mat ], 1]
Cases[_List?(Norm[#] <= max &)] @ mat
DeleteCases[_List?(Norm[#] > max &)] @ mat
```

all give

> ```
> {{80, 14, 0, 67, 3}, {74, 15, 24, 4, 100}, {48, 25, 44, 73, 69}}
> ```

To select columns with norm $\le max$, use `Transpose[mat]`:

```
Select[Norm[#] <= max &]@Transpose[mat]
```

> ```
> {{0, 23, 24, 70, 44}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1];

m = RandomInteger[100, {5, 5}];

max = 130;
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

Rows

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[m, {x_ /; Norm[x] > max}]
```

{{80, 14, 0, 67, 3}, {74, 15, 24, 4, 100}, {48, 25, 44, 73, 69}}

Columns

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[Transpose @ m, {x_ /; Norm[x] > max}]
```

{{0, 23, 24, 70, 44}}

Answer (score 1):

```
SeedRandom[1];

m = RandomInteger[100, {5, 5}];

max = 130;
```

---

Using `SequenceCases`:

Rows

```
SequenceCases[m, s : {x_ /; Norm[x] < max} :> Splice@s]

(*{{80, 14, 0, 67, 3}, {74, 15, 24, 4, 100}, {48, 25, 44, 73, 69}}*)
```

Columns

```
SequenceCases[Transpose@m, s : {x_ /; Norm[x] < max} :> Splice@s]

(*{{0, 23, 24, 70, 44}}*)
```

Using `SequenceReplace`:

Rows

```
SequenceReplace[m, s : {x_ /; Norm[x] > max} :> Nothing]

(*{{80, 14, 0, 67, 3}, {74, 15, 24, 4, 100}, {48, 25, 44, 73, 69}}*)
```

Columns

```
SequenceReplace[Transpose@m, s : {x_ /; Norm[x] > max} :> Nothing]

(*{{0, 23, 24, 70, 44}}*)
```